# Sending SMS in Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation

I connect to internet via Mobile Broadband which is actually a USB 3G Modem. How do I use that to send SMS. For windows they have provided a software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a good deal of research I got WAMMU to work for me...

Comment: You should accept your own answer..also,consider giving the steps as to how you got it working...would be really helpful for users :)

Comment: Yes, can you please provide details on where to get wammu and how to set it up in Ubuntu? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I used a very convoluted manner to make things work.

First up, install **sakis3g** and use it to convert your USB device into a modem.
Connecting to internet using sakis3g is straightforward.

Now, sakis3g does one good thing. It switches your modem if it is not switched. So, use it to switch your modem and you'll have new entries in /dev/ starting with ttyUSB (like ttyUSB0, ttyUSB1, ttyUSB2, ttyUSB3) All those correspond to the various capabilities of your modem. In my E1550 USB0 worked with wammu.

Now, **wammu**.

Run wammu.

Run guided configuration for connecting phone.

Connection type --> USB

Phone type --> None of the above

Connection type --> AT based

Next

USB Port --> /dev/ttyUSB0 (worked for me, try the others if it doesn't)

If wammu recognized it in the next step, you're up!

Connect to the phone, create a message, enjoy!

**Bonus**: To make USSD code see this question [Huawei E353 USSD Codes and Message?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173750/huawei-e353-ussd-codes-and-message)
The tool is gsm-ussd to be obtained [here](http://linux.zum-quadrat.de/downloads/). The command is

```
sudo gsm-ussd *123# -m /dev/ttyUSB*
```

* is the number that works