# Desktop SMS client in Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, sms

Hi I am looking for some kind of script/software that can help me to send SMS from my Ubuntu machine  . A desktop client/application actually by using web services which we use to send sms like way2sms.com or 160by2.com etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending SMS in Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126330/sending-sms-in-ubuntu)

Comment: You mean app to send sms via webservice like way2sms.com? If yes mention it in the question :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go. Create an account at 160by2.com and install php on your system.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli php5-curl curl
```

Paste your number and password where i've mentioned and run this script:

```
<?php
echo"Phone: ";$phno=trim(fgets(STDIN));
echo"Message: ";$msg=trim(fgets(STDIN));
echo"Message Length: ".strlen($msg)."\nSending...";
$yournumber=''; //your number inside the single quotes
$yourpassword='';//your password inside the single quotes
$cur=curl_init("http://160by2.com/re-login");
curl_setopt($cur,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($cur,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"username=$yournumber&password=$yourpassword");
curl_setopt($cur,CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,1);
curl_setopt($cur,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"cookie");
curl_exec($cur);
curl_close($cur);
$cur=curl_init("http://160by2.com/SendSMSAction");
curl_setopt($cur,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($cur,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,1);
curl_setopt($cur,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"cookie");
curl_setopt($cur,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"mobile1=$phno&msg1=$msg&action1=sa65sdf656fdfd");
$x=curl_exec($cur);
curl_close($cur);
echo"\nSent!";
```

Save the script as sms.php.Then on terminal run `php sms.php`

DONE!

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer i have tried and got an error . http://pastebin.com/AeiQvaJG

Comment: `sudo apt-get install curl php5-curl` installs cURL and cURL API for PHP. That'll fix the error.

Comment: @Raja that link is not working . Well anyways dont use pastebin. see [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3133/a-request-for-all-ask-ubuntu-users) why

Comment: @l0n3_shArk Hi i have tried installing php5-curl from synaptic and your script executed successfully but i have not received any message up to now . Thanks man ,your script good idea .

Comment: @Ashu just now i have checked the pastebin link and its fine . but thanks for the info about that :) i am not gonna touch it again .

Comment: @Raja, 160by2 can be slow at delivery at times, but works okay. Welcome!

Comment: @l0n3_shArk Still no message i got , :(

Comment: if i have received i will make mark as accepted answer my friend but your idea is really good +1 .

Comment: @l0n3_shArk same thing with me...it says message sent but no messages received. However, sending from the web delivers the message instantly.

Comment: @everyone, I've edited my code, please note the change, I'm currently using this to text my friends after TRAI imposed restrictions on the number of SMSes sent per day!

Comment: @l0n3_shArk...how to install php? :/ i mean i dint get what to do exactly when u say install php? and how to run the script after that?

Comment: @l0n3_shArk now it work! Thanks.

Comment: @Nirmik `sudo apt-get install php5-cli php5-curl curl`.Then save the script as sms.php.Modify your username, password. Then on terminal run `php sms.php`.

Comment: @l0n3_shArk tested man , you awesome man . thats worked .

Comment: @l0n3_shArk...can i add `#!usr/bin/env php` in the begining to make it like a shell script that can be run by clicking on it? i've done it with python files by adding `#!usr/bin/env python`

Comment: @all...that worked...added the line,made a launcher..and its now workin awesome! just click ;) thanx for the script!! One for way2sms would be even better!

Comment: @l0n3_shArk Its not working anymore, showing a error: "page not found". Could you please update the script?

Comment: @l0n3_shArk hey its not working please update.

Comment: Its not working because the url `http://160by2.com/SendSMSAction` in the code is no loger valid. When I am using their website the url is something like this: `http://m.160by2.com/FebSendSMS?id=DDF62DG9ED**************.7043`. I am trying to find out the correct url, but so far no luck.

Comment: not working. it says that sms is sent but it is not sent actually

Answer (score 3):

It's simple.

Just go register at [CS Networks](http://www.cs-networks.net) and you may send messages from terminal with the following command:

```
wget http://api.cs-networks.net:9011/bin/send?USERNAME=yourusername&PASSWORD=yourpassword&DESTADDR=447123456789&MESSAGE=somemessageSOURCEADDR=test
```

Comment: Welcome & thanks for your answer. Please note that it's asked for a *desktop client/application*

Answer (score -1):

Here is a link for downloading .deb files for both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of sendsms / gsendsms. Sendsms is open source software published under a GNU/GPL license.

https://www.cs-networks.net/index.php/products/toolsandutils/linux-sendsms

It will allow you to send messages from the terminal / or simple GUI under GNOME.