# Is there any way to use Ubuntu with an Android phone?

Tags: usb, android, notification, instant-messaging, sms

Could I plug in my Android phone into my Ubuntu PC via USB cable and have text messages and such appear in my Ubuntu notifications? Or something like that (similar to the Ubuntu for Android application being developed, except I could plug my phone into my PC which is already running Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with '[Android Notifier](http://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/)' application.

The application is simple in premise: when your phone receives texts, incoming calls, media messages, voice-mail or other relevant alerts it pushes these notifications to your Ubuntu screen via Bluetooth or WiFi so that you don’t miss them.The service displays notifications using the systems default notification service(**notify-osd** in case of ubuntu).

Phone-call notification:

[image]

SMS Notification:

[image]

---

**How-To Setup (Tested only on Ubuntu Natty & Ubuntu Precise):**

**On Desktop:**

It requires java.You can get it from [here](https://launchpad.net/~ferramroberto/+archive/java).

Install 'android notifer' on your desktop from [here](http://android-notifier.googlecode.com/files/android-notifier-desktop_0.5.1-0_i386.deb). After installing it , start the application (from accessories/android notifier desktop or search it in dash).It is still using using old gnome-panel notification area applet.So the indicator doesn't appear on unity panel. To run the configuration-window press  `Alt+F2` & type `/usr/share/android-notifier-desktop/run.sh -p`. This will open Android notifier preference.

[image]

If you want to use notify-osd select libnotify also install libnotify-bin package(`sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin`). Initially set '**receive notification from any device**' from device menu.

---

**On Android:**

First install android notifier from [here.](http://android-notifier.googlecode.com/files/AndroidNotifier-0.2.8.apk) or from the [android market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.damazio.notifier&feature=search_result).

[image]

Start the application.Go to 'notification method' If you want to wifi (**Both your laptop & phone has to be connected on the same wifi netwok**.), select wifi, or if you want to use  bluetooth select bluetooth.If you want to use your 3g network or over usb select the option accordingly. Get more help from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/wiki/Setup).

You can select events to notify under main menu->events to notify section.The default options are: **Phone Ring, SMS, MMS, Battery, Voicemail** etc.

---

**Wifi Setup:**

Go to IP/Wifi Option:

Under target IP address select 'custom or host'.

Under custom ip address(es) type your ip address. To view your ip address click network manager on the panel & select connection information.

Under Network protocol section make all the three options(send with udp, send with tcp, sendover cell network) are selected.

Now go back to main menu & click 'Send test notification' to check whether it is working properly.If everything runs smoothly you will get a test notification as notify-osd bubble.

---

**Bluetooth Setup(Recommended):**

If you already paired your device delete pairing. There is a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/issues/detail?id=3&colspec=ID%20Opened%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary) in code that if device is already paired Bluetooth doesn't work.

Under Bluetooth option enable 'auto-enable-bluetooth'.

Now Go back to main menu & try to send a test notification.

It will ask to you to pair your device. Follow onscreen instruction.After successful  pairing it will send  a test notification.

[image]

At this point on android go to **main-menu->notification methods->bluetooth options->target device**.Select your target device.If this is set to "Any device" (the default), the notifications will be sent to the first computer device found.

DONE!

---

**Troubleshooting:**

If anything goes wrong you can check log from **~/.local/share/android-notifier-desktop/android-notifier-desktop.log** file.

[Bluetooth Issues](http://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/issues/detail?id=3&colspec=ID%20Opened%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary)

[Indicator-Applet issue](http://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/issues/detail?id=163&colspec=ID%20Opened%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary).

Report a bug [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-notifier/issues/entry).

Answer (score 1):

The android phones do not have the direct way of installing the PC suite in linux machine. To accomplish that task you will need to install wine.
To install wine type in terminal :

> sudo apt-get install wine1.4

Wine is like a translator that will translate the windows binary to linux's binary and then run it. Of course it will take more of your system resources.
Here are some links that you might want to visit for further knowledge :

> [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29)
>
> http://www.winehq.org/

[Desktop SMS client in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145772/desktop-sms-client-in-ubuntu)

[How can I make usual phone calls using a connected mobile phone?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16305/how-can-i-make-usual-phone-calls-using-a-connected-mobile-phone)

http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android