# Applications in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, sms, zte

I am using Internet on a 3G prepaid Sim using data device ZTE MF190.I want to know about some applications can be used in my Desktop for making calls and sending and receiving text SMS using my Desktop only in Ubuntu 14.04 or Ubuntu 16.04.How can I do it in a easy way?

Comment: This might have what you're looking for http://askubuntu.com/questions/145772/desktop-sms-client-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send/receive sms using your prepaid number via Broadband Modem in Ubuntu, there is **modem-manager-gui** application available.

We can install modem-manager-gui using ubuntu software manager or via command line using :

`sudo apt install modem-manager-gui`

[modem manager gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEtND.png)

Limitation :

- This application work with my edge/umts/hspa modem, but doesn't work
  with my cdma/evdo modem.
- No 'call' menu.

[Summary from their website :](https://linuxonly.ru/cms/page.php?7)

Modem Manager GUI is frontend for ModemManager daemon able to control specific modem functions.
Main features:

- GTK3 interface
- Send and receive SMS messages with messages concatenation.
- Send USSD request and receive answer in system encoding.
- Get modem and SIM information (Device info, Operator name, Mode, IMEI, IMSI/ESN, Signal level)
- Scan available mobile networks
- Control data transmission process and set session traffic and time limits