# Huawei E353 USSD Codes and Message?

Tags: usb, usb-modem, huawei

I am using this device.

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
```

But , i am unable to send and receive messages. And how do i use USSD Code?
Modem works fine on 3g networks.

Only i am not able to check my usage via USSD Codes.

I have treid using `Gammu` But it is not recognizing my modem.

Answer (score 3):

[GSM-USSD](http://linux.zum-quadrat.de/downloads/) is an utility that enable you to send USSD codes via modem.

You need to configure it correctly. [Here is thread](http://mybroadband.co.za/vb/showthread.php/271559-How-to-check-bundle-balance-with-USSD-%28gsm-ussd%29) that gives idea about configuration.

Read [post #13](http://mybroadband.co.za/vb/showthread.php/271559-How-to-check-bundle-balance-with-USSD-%28gsm-ussd%29?p=5177071&viewfull=1#post5177071) also

You can try with `sudo gsm-ussd *123#` or

According to the post A execution command would be

```
sudo gsm-ussd *123# -m /dev/`dmesg | grep "usb 1-3" | tail -n 1 -c 8`
```

Where *123# is your ussd command.

Comment: But it doesn't even detect my modem. How will it work then?

Comment: you said your modem is working fine!! modem will be represented under `/dev/ttyUSB0` - `/dev/ttyUSB3` you need to issue command as in post 13

Comment: It will be better if you pull it off and reconnect. Sometime the utility fails after you connect to internet. :(

Comment: How do i find the port , for issuing command?

Comment: post 13 command will do that for you.  See a sample command. I have updated the post